# Runtime permission check API 23+: Cannot resolve symbol 'Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

Tags: android

I'm trying to check a permission in API 23 and above like this:

```
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

But it can't find `Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

This is because in my manifest the permission is set up like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

So I changed it to this and now it works:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Can you not use `uses-permission` to check permissions at runtime? Do I have to change all my `uses-permission` to `permission` in my app to make it work checking permissions at runtime in API 23+?

EDIT: the error I am getting in Android Studio is:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

Comment: No. `uses-permission` is the correct tag.  What do you mean "can't find it?"

Comment: @DeeV Android studio gives an inline error "Cannot resolve symbol 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'"

Comment: In Java or the manifest?  It doesn't make sense to me that it wouldn't find a reference to a constant.

Comment: @DeeV In Java. I know. I don't get it either....

Comment: Did u import manifest package

Comment: @DeeV I think I got it. Check my answer. Does that seem right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok I figured out what the problem was:

I was using

```
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, com.mypackage.myapp.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

What I needed was:

```
int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

So it looks like using auto import in Android Studio was a bad idea lol.

Comment: Yes.  This would be an issue if you were importing the wrong Manifest class, though why would your app have a Manifest class itself?

Comment: @DeeV Well that Manifest is my manifest, as in my apps manifest. Why wouldn't I have it..? All Android apps do...

Comment: Not necessarily.  You have to be creating certain things like custom permissions or permission groups which you seem to be doing (which is also why `<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` worked).

Comment: @DeeV Oh, well I do have this entry in my manifest for Google Cloud Messaging: `<permission
        android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />` Maybe that is what did it? I just copy/pasted it from the GCM sample app. I guess that is a custom permission?

Comment: Yep.  That's the reason.  I always thought that requirement was silly, but it's needed.

Comment: Changed Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH to android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, It's worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I've done it before:

```
// inside my class
private static final String[] INITIAL_PERMS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
private static final int REQUEST = 1337;

// inside a method
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    requestPermissions(INITIAL_PERMS, REQUEST);
}
```

I would lie to you if I told you I remember why I'm using the number 1337, and I would assume this could be any number, but I set this up some months ago and have never changed it again.

Comment: This is a nice example, but it doesn't really address the question.